# Play 2.0 eclipsify command with sources broken?

Tags: scala, view, playframework-2.0

Update: I found another one with a similar problem http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/c502be978a320cb7/28bc3a3253933aed?show_docid=28bc3a3253933aed

If I run Play and then try to do an eclipsify with sources Play says it can't find the files.

> [todolist] $ eclipsify with-source=true [info] About to create Eclipse
>   project files for your project(s). [warn]  [NOT FOUND  ]
>   org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.9.1!scala-library.jar(src) (0ms)

Steps to reproduce.

1. Command: Play new test
2. Accept the name
3. Command: 1, Choose Create a simple Scala application
4. Command: cd test
5. Command: play
6. Command: eclipsify with-source=true

I will a have a working eclipse project and the referenced jar files.
However I won't have the source code compiled into the jars.

Comment: There is definitely something wrong with your project or Play 2.0 installation, as I can assure you it works fine for me.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either, but maybe our ivy cache is messed up?

Answer (score 2):

Try to do a `play clean` and execute the command again. If it still fails please raise a bug in [lighthouse](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/overview)

Comment: This worked for me.  There is a long list of other jars for which no sources downloaded.  It makes me wonder how the choice is made whether to put the source and doc jars into the repo.